# jquery one function to send all forms and fetch data

Tags: jquery, ajax, forms, post, submit

So my goal was to have a function in my jQuery code, that allowed me to do case statements that then allowed me to do what I needed with each form, without having to re-type the whole post function.

UPDATE my fix is at the very bottom of this question

e.g.

```
    function fetch(e,formstring)
{

    $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: 'system/classes/core.php',
      data: formstring,
      dataType: 'json',
      contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=utf-8",
      success: function(data){
          $.each(data, function(i, obj) {

               switch (e) { 
                 case 1:
                  $.each(obj, function(key, val) {
                     alert(key+" - "+val);
                  });
                 break;
                 case 2:
                    alert("sucker");
                 break;
                 case 3:
                 //LoginSript

                    $('#rightheader').html(obj.code);
                 break;
                 case 4:
                 //WelcomePage/Signup
                    $('#window').html(obj.code);
                 break;
               }
         });
      },
      error: function(data){
      $.each(data,function(i,myinfo){
            alert(i);       
          });
      }
    });
    return false;
}
```

While fetching data seems to work, submitting forms seems not.

```
$(function() {

    $("form#login").submit(function(){
        shownotify(1,"Please hold we are login you in.");
        fetch(1,$(this).serialize());   
    });
});
```

I thought I was doing everything right.

just also so you can see here is the show notify function too.

```
    function shownotify(e,msg)
{
    if(e==1){$('#notify').show();};
    if(e==2){$('#notify').hide();};

    $('#notifyheader').html("Please Hold");
    $('#notifytext').html(msg); 
}
```

I am wondering if I have an error, or am I doing this wrong?

Comment: Please add your solution to a propper *answer* otherwise others won't know this has been solved.

Comment: done did not know I could answer my own questions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way I fixed the error was by setting a setTimeout function around the $(function(){})

```
setTimeout(function(){
$(function() {

    $("form#login").submit(function(){
        shownotify(1,"Please hold we are login you in.");
        fetch(2,$(this).serialize());   
    });
});
},1000);
```